# Bootstrap 3 CSS causing div height to be zero

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, onsen-ui

I'm using onsen-ui for mobile app devl. I was trying to incorporate this login screen I saw on this page: http://cssdeck.com/labs/simply-login-form

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="login">
  <div class="titulo" style="vertical-align:baseline;height:14px;">Staff Login</div>
  <form action="#" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" required title="Username required" placeholder="Username" data-icon="U">
      <input type="password" required title="Password required" placeholder="Password" data-icon="x">
      <div class="olvido">
        <div class="col"><a href="#" title="Ver Carásteres">Register</a></div>
          <div class="col"><a href="#" title="Recuperar Password">Fotgot Password?</a></div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="enviar">Submit</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

What was happening was the div.titulo and a.enviar elements were somehow being set to height=0. I couldn't understand why this was happening, it works perfectly fine on the site I listed above and even when I copied the same code to an empty html file. I did some digging and after much research I found this bootstap css property to be the culprit:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The original site I got this code from is not using bootstrap, but my application is...and it seems this bootstrap css is conflicting with the code. I commented out the above from boostrap css file.....take a look at before and after pictures of my login form:

Not Working (with bootstrap box-sizing css):

[image: Not working]
<sub>(source: [imageno.com](http://www.imageno.com/image.php?id=hnqqzk0sfn90&kk=1698558439))</sub>

Working (without bootstrap box-sizing css):

[image: Working]
<sub>(source: [imageno.com](http://www.imageno.com/image.php?id=in8mdfdvvql2&kk=2088245172))</sub>

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? What exactly is this box sizing and border-box and why is it causing div height to be zero at times?

Update...here is the CSS provided from that site:

```
.login {
    width: 300px;
    height: 285px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #1e1e1e;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

.login .titulo {
    width: 298px;
    height: 14px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #121212;
    border: #2d2d2d solid 1px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.login form {
    width: 240px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.login form input[type=text], .login form input[type=password] {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    border: none;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    background: #141414;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.login form input[type=text] {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-top: #0b0b0b solid 1px;
    background: #141414 url(http://dev.dhenriquez.com/test-img/icons/111-user.png) 10px center no-repeat;
}

.login form input[type=password] {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-top: #0b0b0b 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #353535 1px solid;
    background: #141414 url(http://dev.dhenriquez.com/test-img/icons    /54-lock.png) 10px center no-repeat;
}

.login form .enviar {
    width: 240px;
    height: 12px;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: none;
    border-top: #4eb2a8 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #161616 1px solid;
    background: #349e92;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px #1d7464, 0 1px #7bb8b3;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.login .olvido {
    width: 240px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.login .olvido .col {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

.login .olvido .col a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px Arial;
}
```

Comment: Could you post all css which are you using? Bootstrap itself is not causing 0 height, see bootply: http://www.bootply.com/jCz1gi5Hb3

Comment: hello kybernaut...thank you for your reply. Actually even in the example you provided you can see that the "Staff Login" div is not staying within its parent element and is going into the textbox below. Try removing bootstrap and I believe it will work. I added the CSS I'm using for this code.

Comment: My answer updated below.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so let's solve your problem, in link titulo, you have hardcoded height:

```
<div class="titulo" style="vertical-align:baseline;height:14px;">Staff Login</div>
```

So first, you should get rid of the inline `vertical-align:baseline;height:14px;`

The very same is in your css, which has to be removed:

```
.login .titulo {
    height: 14px;
```

[...]

Was that what you were looking for?
http://www.bootply.com/jCz1gi5Hb3

P.S. The same kind of trick in css is with "Submit" button.

Comment: but what if I want to have a height, i mean, if I want that div.titulo to have a height of 30px how would I do that?

Comment: You can set it there, but if you'll set the height, which is lower than the real size of content, youll get this kind of trouble. Better way is to set for example line-height: 30px, and no padding or something like that, but solution is up to you.